# How can I optimize the creation of this adjacency matrix?

Tags: matlab, network-programming, adjacency-matrix

I want to create an adjacency matrix in MATLAB to simulate roads network in a generic city with a chess layout, in particular then each node can be connected with just his prime neighbors (max 8 link per node). I wrote this code which produces the desired output:

```
rng('shuffle');

NRoads = 25;
CitySize = sqrt(NRoads);

PCross = 0.8;
Adj = zeros(NRoads);

for i = 1:NRoads
    for j = i+1:NRoads

        x = rand;
        if ismember(j, [i+1, i+CitySize, i+CitySize+1]) && x < PCross

            Adj(i, j) = 1;

        end;

    end;
end;

Adj = Adj | Adj';
```

But I am wondering if there is an optimized way to do so (for example, without the double for loop or a specific function).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, your code is randomly filling the first, fifth, and sixth off-diagonals with ones (at a given rate `PCross`), then adding that matrix to a transpose of itself. Your loops can therefore be replaced by three calls to [`diag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html):

```
Adj = (diag(rand(1, NRoads-1), 1) + ...
       diag(rand(1, NRoads-5), 5) + ...
       diag(rand(1, NRoads-6), 6)) > (1-PCross);
Adj = Adj | Adj.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Even without the [clever observation that gnovice did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52725603/7328782), it is easy to simplify the code.

The inner loop:

```matlab
    for j = i+1:NRoads
        x = rand;
        if ismember(j, [i+1, i+CitySize, i+CitySize+1]) && x < PCross
            Adj(i, j) = 1;
        end
    end
```

Loops over all `j` then sees if `j` is either of 3 given values. Why not just loop over those three values only?

```matlab
    for j = [i+1, i+CitySize, i+CitySize+1]
        x = rand;
        if j <= NRoads && x < PCross
            Adj(i, j) = 1;
        end
    end
```

This of course no longer needs a loop:

```matlab
    j = [i+1, i+CitySize, i+CitySize+1];
    x = rand(1,3);
    j = j(j <= NRoads & x < PCross); % note elementwise &, not &&
    Adj(i, j) = 1;
```